# Sci-fi movie/series with humans kept as pets by aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

I’m trying to identify a sci-fi movie or TV series I saw at a video store many years ago. It may have been a TV movie and was part of a series or anthology. The specific installment I can remember was about a family of giant aliens, including a child alien who had a terrarium with humans kept as pets. It was on VHS before 2000 so it can’t be more recent than that. It was live action and in color.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Just to clarify, was this live-action or animated?

Comment: Can we assume this was live action and in colour?

Comment: Yes, live action and in color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the subject matter and date, it's possible this is [*Josh Kirby: Time Warrior! Chap. 2: The Human Pets*](https://imdb.com/title/tt0113485) (1995) wherein the titular hero and his friends are captured by a giant baby-alien and kept as pets (until they escape, of course).

Encyclopedia.com gives the [following blurb](https://www.encyclopedia.com/arts/culture-magazines/josh-kirby-time-warrior-chapter-2-human-pets):

> Josh and his friends now find themselves in the year 70,370—held hostage by the enormous Fatlings, who regard their human finds as pet-like action toys.

Comment: Yes, that is it! I just looked up the VHS cover and it is definitely the one.

Comment: So La Planete Sauvage is not what you are looking for, but do check it out as a possible source or inspiration for your film.